# How to "merge" a git branch when I forgot to create a master branch

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I've recently switched to Git from CVS/SVN and so far enjoying it.  However, in my latest dev cycle, I forgot a critical step in creating a master branch before creating my dev branch.

In my normal cycle, I have my trunk (stable code), and then my maintenance branch in which we perform maintenance releases.  Within that maintenance branch, we have our dev branches for individual bugs.

Usually, my maintenance branch follows my versions.  So in my trunk I'll have my Major versions (ie: ver 1, ver 2, ver 3).  Then my maintenance branch (ie: 1.1, 2.1, 2.2, etc).  Then within my maintenance branch, my dev branch for this release (ie: 1.2.1, 2.1.3, etc).

In my last cycle, I was working on 2.2.1.  My last release was 2.1.8. I accidentally branched from my 2.1 branch and did work on it, instead of first creating a 2.2 branch.  Now, when I want to merge my changes back, I don't have a 2.2 branch to merge back into.

What I "should" have done was merge my 2.1 branch back into the trunk (v2) and then branched 2.2 from the trunk and then 2.2.1 from the 2.2 branch.

Now that I do not have a 2.2 branch and my 2.2.1 branch incorrectly comes off 2.1, how do I save myself?

There has been a lot of dev work done in 2.2.1 already.

```
|-1.0
|-2.0
   |-2.1
      |-2.1.1
      |-2.1.2
      |-....
      |-2.1.8
      |-2.2.1        <---- wrong place!!!
```

Should have been:

```
|-1.0
|-2.0
   |-2.1
      |-2.1.1
      |-2.1.2
      |-....
      |-2.1.8
   |-2.2
      |-2.2.1
```

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in git you can always change things later and move things around.  So don't panic.  First, create a copy of your entire directory to run the tests on a different copy "just in case" before doing it on your main copy.  It'll make you feel a bit safer.

What you need to do is:

1) create the 2.2 branch where you want it to be.  IE, check out where you *should* have branched from (something like `git checkout v2.1` I think, but it's hard to tell from your description).  Then create the 2.2 branch there with something like `git checkout -b v2.2`.

2) Then, you need to move your 2.2.1 branch over to the v2.2 branch.  This is actually fairly easily done with `git rebase`, which functionally moves a branch from one spot in a tree to another.  You'd do this with `git checkout v2.2.1` followed by `git rebase v2.2`, which will move the changes made in the v2.2.1 branch over into the new v2.2 branch.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this today, but ended up with a bit of a mess.  It seems as though it re-applies the changes into the v2.2 branch itself.  But doesn't actually prune the 2.2.1 branch and regraft it in 2.2.  So when I look at my log, I find the same commit in the original v2.2.1 branch, and in the new v2.2 branch.

Comment: ahh...  Yeah, the v2.2 branch needs to be created first.  I'll adjust my text.

Comment: no, wait...  the above text is right.  But it does move the 2.2.1 branch to the tip of the 2.2 branch.  If you wanted it somewhere else, you still need to flag where in the tree you want it with either a branch or a tag and then use git rebase to put it there.

Comment: I'm very confused.  Perhaps my workflow is no longer appropriate with git as it was with CVS/SVN, but I was hoping to stay within the same structure.  Or perhaps it is that I am having difficulty reading the log graphs that come with git vs those I used to create with CVS.  That is, have Master->v2.2->v2.2.1.  Then when done with v2.2.1 I can merge back into v2.2.  But when I try to move the branch as indicated, I see that I have all the changes from within v2.2.1 applied directly within 2.2.  But when I look at the graph, it looks like the original branch hasn't moved.

Comment: Well, git does allow for very different models than CVS and SVN does.  CVS/SVN are very limited and handle merging, etc, very poorly (you can do it, but it's functionally a pain).  What *I* do for branch management is described here: http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Git_Workflow  I've found this workflow to be very helpful, and follows a few very simple steps (the document is long because I drew lots of pretty pictures):  1) always commit a patch to the lowest version it should be applied to.  EG, if it's a fix, then apply it to the earliest release it makes sense to apply it to.

Comment: 2) routinely merge the lower version branches into the higher version branches to collect all the fixes into the latest development copy.  With CVS/SVN you had to spend a lot more effort applying a patch to all the right places, and frequently missed applying them to a branch that should have gotten them.  Let git handle that for you now.  And use tags to make release snapshots and create the branch only later after it's needed (from the tag point).